# WPF Datagrid Columns return empty values on some fields

Tags: sql-server, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a problem with my datagrid in WPF in my SQL Server query. The results were working fine but in my datagrid it returns some empty columns where values are missing.

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT  
    DATENAME(dw, CAST(DATEPART(m, TASK.Date) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
                 CAST(DATEPART(d, TASK.Date) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
                 CAST(DATEPART(yy, TASK.DATE) AS VARCHAR)) AS 'Day Name',
    EMP.Employee_ID AS 'Employee ID',
    EMP.Employee_LastName + ' ' + EMP.Employee_FirstName AS 'Employee Name',
    TASK.Task_Assigned AS 'No. of Assigned Task',
    TASK.Task_Completed AS 'No. of Completed Task',
    TASK.Task_Remaining AS 'No. of Remaining Task',
    TASK.Total_Tasks AS 'Total No. Of Tasks Including Lastweek',
    CAST(Task.Date As DATE) AS 'Date'
FROM
    [dbo].Employee_Table EMP
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].Tasks_Table TASK ON EMP.Employee_ID = TASK.Employee_ID
```

The output is this

[SQL Server 2012 Execute Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAeYg.png)

But after running this in my WPF application, this is what I get

[WPF execution of stored proc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lidqt.png)

Here is how I run my SQL query using vb.net

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("")
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

    sqlCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[DisplayTTM]"
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    sqlCommand.Connection = conn

    conn.Open()

    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    objDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    objDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "TeamTaskManager")

    dgrid_MyTTM.DataContext = ds

    conn.Close()
```

Here is my datagrid wpf code.

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgrid_MyTTM" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TeamTaskManager}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">
 </DataGrid>
```

PS. when I use `ds.getXml()` I see that it gets the value from the query but doesn't output them on screen. Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've alredy found my answer I just do it like this

```
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day" Binding="{Binding Path='a'}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee ID" Binding="{Binding Path='b'}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Binding="{Binding Path='c'}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="No. of Assigned Task" Binding="{Binding Path='d'}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="No. of Assigned Task Completed" Binding="{Binding Path='e'}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="No. of Assigned Task Remaining" Binding="{Binding Path='f'}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total No. of Task including Yesterday" Binding="{Binding Path='g'}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path='h'}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

And suddenly got all my records on the table. Thanks guys.